# When debugging an Angular application that uses ngrx how can I find the line of code that dispatched a given action?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Currently I am working with a project that is getting pretty complicated. It uses Angular and ngrx to manage state change. A common problem I have is working with a particular effect or piece of state and needed to know where the related action was dispatched. Sometimes this is straight forward as there is only 1 line of code that dispatches the action and sometimes this is complicated as there are several. It is also difficult to understand what happens as a consequence of actions as it could cause components to change and effects to trigger (which dispatch more actions).

I am aware of [Redux Devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) but this isn't sufficient as it only tells us the order of actions and the state changes. Breakpoints aren't sufficient as a breakpoint in the effects, reducer, or component does not have a stack trace that includes where the action was dispatched.

What you recommend? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

We encourage that the action has a source and the event as `type`, `[Source] Event`, e.g. `[Customers Page] Loaded`. This is what we call good action hygiene, because it's clear where the action is dispatched. For more info see the [Good Action Hygiene Rule](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/good-action-hygiene.md) from the NgRx ESLint plugin.

Comment: Seems kinda odd no? That means you can't have an action dispatch in different places. Seems unnecessarily restricted.

Comment: Depends.... creating an action is simple, debugging might be harder. We also encourage to see an action as a unique event in the system, with this philosophy an action can't be dispatched from multiple places.

Comment: Not necessarily @RyanBadour , the source is a dynamic value. The same action can be dispatched from different places with a different source value. In other words: The action will follow the same logic regardless of what dispatched it, but the value of "source" can have the name of the dispatcher (service, component, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I found Redux DevTools very comfortable, which is incorporated in chrome. Thanks to it you can reconstruct all the steps that are made between actions and effects.